# how to extract text from image of pdf file using java?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pdf

I am doing a java web application project in which i have to extract text from images of PDF file. Can anyone knows how to do it? I tried PDF box but it only displays text of PDF. Secondly tesseract only works for stand alone applications. How to extract image data in maven spring web application?